# Upgrading to Spring-boot 2.3.1.RELEASE and kafka, can't find kafka.utils.TestUtils

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

A project that was running our test suite fine with `Spring-boot 2.2.6.RELEASE` and `Spring-kafka 2.4.1.RELEASE` is encountering issues when upgrading to `Spring-boot 2.3.1.RELEASE` and `Spring-kafka 2.5.3.RELEASE`. It seems that it cannot find kafka.utils.TestUtils.

I've tried leaving the spring-kafka version blank to allow spring-boot to pull a compatible version, but the error still exists.

build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.3.1.RELEASE"
  api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.1.RELEASE"
  api "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.5.3.RELEASE"
  api "org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:3.0.9.RELEASE"

  testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.3.1.RELEASE"
  testImplementation "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:2.5.3.RELEASE"
}
```

And the error I'm seeing:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/utils/TestUtils
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.customizeContext(EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader.customizeContext(AbstractContextLoader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/utils/TestUtils
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker$EmbeddedZookeeper.<init>(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:655)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.utils.TestUtils
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

Is there some obvious compatibility issue I'm missing, or some transient dependency that needs to be excluded?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone encounters the same issue, the solution was to drop the version from the `spring-kafka` and `spring-kafka-test` and to add the test classifier for the test:

```
testImplementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: "kafka_2.12", classifier: "test"
```